# how does uploading a file through input type = file open the windows dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

When we click on choose file. It opens dialog window to choose a file to upload, but I want to know what really happens when we click on choose file and how does that diolog window appears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is being handled by your browser. It is built in a native language for your operating system and it takes the input event and displays the file dialog. It then takes whatever file you choose and opens an HTTP stream with that file to your server to upload it. It has nothing to do with HTML or JS.

Comment: #David, Thanks for your comment, But i need to know in depth, there should be some event which gets trigger when we click on choose file. I need to know what that event is. And how does that  call dialog window for file upload. My operating system is windows.

Comment: That's just it though: there is **no** JS event being called. It is all done by the browser itself. I don't have access to their source, so I can't tell you exactly what each browser is using, but as an example, here's how to show a file dialog in VC#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984392(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> there should be some event which gets trigger when we click on choose
>   file. I need to know what that event is.

See [GlobalEventHandlers.onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) , [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) , [4.10.5.1.18 File Upload state (type=file)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file))

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
input.onchange = function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.files)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 defines a files property for all  controls. This collection is a FileList, which is an array-like structure called FileList containing File objects for each selected file in the control (remember, HTML5 allows multiple file selection in these controls). So at any point in time, you can get access to the files a user has selected using code similar to this:

```
<input type="file" id="your-files" multiple>
<script>
var control = document.getElementById("your-files");
control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

    // When the control has changed, there are new files

    var i = 0,
        files = control.files,
        len = files.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        console.log("Filename: " + files[i].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
    }

}, false);
</script></code>
```

This relatively simple code listens for the change event on the file control. When the event fires, it signifies that the file selection has changed, and the code iterates through each File object and outputs its information. Keep in mind that the files property is always accessible from JavaScript, so you don’t have to wait for change to try to read it.

For more information please check the below URLs.

https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/08/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-1/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select